# Regression analysis terminology

Tags: regression, machine-learning, anova, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I am running a machine learning algorithm where all of my independent variables are categorical. However, instead of fitting all of my features into the model all at once and getting static co-efficients, I'm iteratively running and fitting through all the data in my testing sample and getting dynamic co-efficients for predictors, depending upon the presence of other predictors. This allows me to establish a non-linear relationship between the predictors. I'm also obtaining a better R-squared and seeing visible predictive improvements.

What is this type of approach to regression called?

Comment: Because there is chance you are over-fitting have you considered looking at a cross-validation check?

Comment: I'm indeed doing cross-validation as I'm running the tests on my test sample using the feature vectors that I have obtained from my training data.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,you are doing Multiple (Linear) regression with forward stepwise selection of variables. 
In case you are using R,you may achieve the same results with **MASS** package with `stepAIC()`.

You can find more details [here](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I was thinking I was doing something along the lines of a generalized additive model? Because I am not doing this to get rid any predictors/features for my model.